# How to write select query in mysql with dynamic table name and dynamic column name

Tags: mysql

[image]

Above is the table structure of database. For each ‘form_id’ in ‘ap_forms ‘ there is a dynamic table with dynamic column names like ap_form_{form_id}.
Columns in this table will created dynamically by element_id and option_id combination. (eg: for element_id=1 and option_id=2 then column name= element_1_2).
I want the query result from these tables and this will looks like

[image]

I tried with dynamic query and I think we can’t create dynamic query with dynamic table name and dynamic column name. Please help me to get the above query result.

Comment: How does the dynamic table & column are created? From MySQL Stored procedure or from an app (PHP, nodejs etc.)?

Comment: Use [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: It is created from PHP application.

Comment: Tried out with prepared statement. But the table and column are different(dynamic) for each row result, it is not working.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You should mention that table & column created through PHP app and provide some example on how you do it. Also, try to see the possibility of applying the same method in creating the dynamic table & column to generate the dynamic select query.